# Continuous random variables unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

I am currently having some difficulties solving this question...

> If a point is chosen uniformly at random from the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (that is, the set$$\{(x_1,\ldots,x_n) : x_1^2+\cdots+x_n^2\leq1\},$$and $L_n$ is the distance of the point from the origin, what is $E(L_n)$?

**My attempt at the question**

I know in the case for a unit disk, the distance is just $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, and the join density function would be $\frac{1}{\pi}$, and integration would be very easy in polar coordinates. However, I am not sure how to grasp this question.

Comment: The only higher dimensional geometry you need to know is that the content of an $n$-dimensional sphere with radius $r$ is $c_nr^n$ for some constant $c_n$. This lets you determine the cdf of $L_n$, since the event that $L_n$ is less than $\ell$ is a sphere of radius $\ell$, whose content must be divide by the content of the whole ball.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $F(r)=P[L \le r] = r^n$, and $F'(r) = n r^{n-1}$.

Hence $EL = \int_0^1 r F'(r)dr = {n \over n+1}$.

Comment: Thank you for the response! What is $EL$? And cold you explain how you got the $r^n$. Thank you very much.

Comment: The volume of the $n$ sphere of radius $r$ divided by the volume of radius one. The volume must scale as $r^n$ so you don't need to compute the constants. $EL$ is the expected value of $L$???

Comment: I want to show that if a point is chosen uniformly at random from a high dimensional unit ball, it is likely to be very close to the boundary. Thus, I am trying to use Markov's inequality to show that Ln->1 in probability as n->infinity. How would this be done?