# Using Markov's inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

If a point is chosen uniformly at random from the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (that is, the set {($x_1$, $\dots$, $x_n$) : $x_1^{2}$+$\cdots$+$x_n^2$$\leq$$1$}), and $L_n$ is the distance of the point from the origin, I found that $E(L_n)$ is $\frac{n}{n+1}$.

However, I want to show that if a point if chosen uniformly at random from a high dimensional unit ball it is likely to be very close to the boundary. Hence, I want to use Markov's inequality to show that $L_n$$\rightarrow$$1$ in probability as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

I know that $P(X\geq t)\leq\frac{E(X)}{t}$ for any $t>0$, but I have difficulties proceeding after this.

Comment: I am porting my comment over from that thread -- Markov's inequality seems to point the wrong way so to speak. Since this problem has been reduced to 1 dimensional  and you were given a CDF-- use the CDF... for $\delta \in (0,1)$  you have $P(L\leq 1-\delta) = (1-\delta)^n \leq \exp(-\delta n)$

Comment: related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3562951/continuous-random-variables-unit-ball-in-mathbb-rn

Answer (score 2):

Let $D_n$ be the distance from the boundary so $D_n=1-L_n$ and $\mathbb E[D_n]=\frac{1}{n+1}$  and $\mathbb P(D_n\gt t )\lt \frac{1}{t(n+1)}$

Then, given any positive $\epsilon$ and $\delta$, for any $n> \frac{1}{\delta \epsilon}-1$ you have  $\mathbb P(D_n\gt \epsilon )\lt \frac{1}{\epsilon/(\delta \epsilon)}=\delta$

and so $D_n \to 0$ in probability as $n$ increases, and thus $L_n \to 1$ in probability

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain how you got $n> \frac{1}{\delta \epsilon}-1$?

Comment: @jacquesadit00  You want $n$ big enough to use an $\epsilon-\delta$ argument for the limit. How big is *enough*?  You want $\frac1{t(n+1)} \lt \delta$ when $t=\epsilon$.  This is $\frac1{\epsilon(n+1)} \lt \delta$ and $\frac1{n+1} \lt \delta\epsilon$, i.e. $n+1 \gt \frac1{\delta\epsilon}$ and $n \gt \frac1{\delta\epsilon}-1$

Answer (score 0):

$P(L_n<t) \sim t^{n-1}$, hence the limit is 0 if $t<1$ and 1 if $t\ge1$. In this case convergence in distribution implies convergence in probability.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer. Could you explain how you got $t^{n-1}$?

Comment: I suspect that $P(L_n\le t) = t^{n}$ for $0 \lt t \lt 1$, but this does not affect the argument